# cygwin compile error in sys/_types.h

Tags: c++, cygwin

I am trying to use cywin to get some linux code building on a win32 machine.

I get the following VS.net 2003 error in ym compiler:

"c:\cygwin\usr\include\sys_types.h(15): error C2144: syntax error : '__int64' should be preceded by ';'
"

and

c:\cygwin\usr\include\sys_types.h(15): error C2501: '**extension**' : missing storage-class or type specifiers

The code line is

```
__extension__ typedef long long _off64_t;
```

Obviously I am missing something here but I have never used cygwin before and this is killing me.

I want to be able to at least compile my CPP files on my win32 machine for a few reasons.

(this is just the first two errors of hundreds it looks like)

thanks,
tim

EDIT:

the simple workaround I have chosen as the answer - though I do understand that is not as complete or as desirable as using gcc to compile...
This is a quick and dirty compilation so that I can use my familiar tools before trying to integrate with linux machines.  (oh the joys of cross-platform development)

I've voted up each of those answers so far and appreciate the help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the **extension** macro may not be defined. You may want to do a text search on your cygwin header dir to see if this is the case. If so, make sure that you header search path is defined correctly, etc.

Comment: Also, note that in this case, blanking the macro works re: jpalcek below. Obviously you have to be careful what you do this with though.

Answer (score 5):

I could be wrong, but the cygwin headers could be made specifically for compiling using the cygwin gcc, not visual studio. Try compiling using gcc/g++ in cygwin.

EDIT: I may be possible to use Visual Studio, this page (for another project) seems to imply that you can compile something with vc++/cygwin. http://opensg.vrsource.org/trac/wiki/BuildVS2005Cygwin.

You may want to check it out.

EDIT2: Also See: http://www.coin-or.org/OS/documentation/node14.html

EDIT3: I would guess that the best coarse of action would be to make sure that visual studio searches the standard windows paths first. So if there is a system `<sys/types.h>`, that may be preferred over the cygwin version.

Answer (score 4):

The `__extension__` keyword is a gcc extension to denote code that uses gcc extensions (in this case `long long`), so it doesn't blow up in pedantic mode. If you can, try compiling your code with gcc.

Comment: Could this be fixed by #defining the keyword to ' '?

Comment: i'll try ggc ass well, but I also #defined __extension__ and it seems to behave a lot better.

Comment: If that works, it's OK. The keyword doesn't have any real meaning, anyway. However, I was a bit worried about the gcc extensions that MSVC doesn't have - eg. extended asm, compound literals?, variable-length arrays etc. Had the source contained these, you would have no other option than gcc

Answer (score 2):

In C++, any name preceded (or containing) a double underscore is a name reserved for a particular implementation, in this case GNU C++. MS C++ will use other names. Bottom line - you can't compile g++ sources with MS C++, or vice versa, if the sources use such names.