# How to build GSL with msvc2010?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, shared-libraries, gsl

I'm working with Qt 4.8.3 and QtCreator, which I've compiled with msvc2010 as per the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113400/compiling-qt-4-8-2-for-visual-studio-2012).  Now however I need to link to GSL (Gnu Scientific Library), but currently I only know how to build it with g++ which produces linker errors just as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579556/cygwin-compile-error-in-sys-types-h), undoubtedly for the reason given in the answer by @EvanTeran.  However, in my case, building Qt with g++ via cygwin is probably not an option--I've just come off a multi-day nightmare during which I tried to do just this, but could not, as recorded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217734/cant-build-qt-in-windows-from-source-perl-installed-but-still-cant-find-heade).  Surely there is a way to build gsl with msvc2010, but how?  I have VS 2012 Express installed (though I've never used it before) in case there's a solution using it.

**EDIT:** Looking at CMake, it seems the best I can to is to manually create an entire hierarchy of CMakeLists.txt files for GSL.  That's just a little too much so instead I've put a 100pt. bounty on the question mentioned above.  Solving my problem the Visual Studio route (here) OR with g++ will get the bounty and the answer to both questions.

**Update:**  The answer below worked great, but not seamlessly, possibly because I actually needed to compile under VS2012.  A few tweaks to the code were required, such as explicit casts, which were tolerated under the previous compiler apparently but not mine.  Otherwise things proceeded pretty smoothly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CMake and create your own build from [this repository](https://github.com/ampl/gsl) for whatever Visual Studio version you are using. Check out [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467869/1254352) by @vitaut for more details.

Comment: You'll get this bounty as soon as the system lets me award it.  Nice find, though I had to do a little tweaking (will describe shortly).

Comment: Seems like the site has moved to http://brgladman.org/oldsite/computing/gnu_scientific_library.php

Comment: This answer is a exemplifies why link only answers lose their value over time.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Link is now clickbait, and has dangerous risk

Comment: @Grandtour thanks for the info. This answer is a few years old now and using CMake, like vitaut suggested in his answer is more straightforward and should be preferred. All credits to him! Of course I've removed the old URL from the post.

Answer (score 21):

I have implemented CMake build support for GSL here: https://github.com/ampl/gsl

[CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) can either generate a Visual Studio solution or NMake makefiles. For example:

```
> git clone git://github.com/ampl/gsl.git
> cd gsl
> cmake .
-- Building for: Visual Studio 10
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
...
```

This generates the solution (`GSL.sln`) and project files for Visual Studio 2010.

This CMake build script is now included in the `contrib` directory of the GSL Git repository `git://git.savannah.gnu.org/gsl.git`.

As of May 2014, building shared libraries (DLLs) is supported as well with `GSL_SHARED` option.

Comment: Thanks vitaut.  I trust you have tried it out with a test program?  And this this also include gsl_cblas?  (Not that it isn't already useful.)

Comment: I am using it myself and the tests that come with GSL are handled in the CMake script so you can build and run them. gslcblas is included as well.

Comment: pity doesnot support dll. I added line to set dll on, but got error when linking.

Comment: @squid Try adding SHARED to add_library: add_library(gsl SHARED ${GSL_SOURCES})

Comment: Just now I managed to build gls on windows very easily. Your work is really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @hkuwenchao Great. Don't forget to cast your vote if it was helpful =)

Comment: @vitaut thanks for sharing your work. I got it from master/contrib and it was really useful. I greatly appreciated the RUN_TESTS project.